# std::vector с индексами enum

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-то задавать индексы `enum`ом у `std::vector`?

Пример того, что имею в виду:

```
enum name_index {t1,t2,t3,t4};
std::vector<type> vec;
```

доступ к элементу:

```
vec[t1];//vec[0]
vec[t2];//vec[1]
vec[t3];//vec[2]
vec[t4];//vec[3]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, по сути `enum` - это блок констант поэтому код ниже вполне работает.

```
enum t{
   A,B,C,D
};

int main() {
    int m[4];
    m[A] = 1;
    m[B] = 2;
    m[C] = 3;
    m[D] = 4;
    for (int i : m)
       cout <<i;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/lIXYLZ

Comment: Единственно, надо быть осторожным, если где-то написано `enum t {a, b, c = 15, d };`

Answer (score 6):

`enum` в С++ бывает разный. Если просто `enum` - то преобразование неявное (вам это уже показали), но если более современный `enum class` - то тут нужно явное приведение типа

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class t{
   A,B,C,D
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int m[4];
    m[static_cast<int>(t::A)] = 1;
    m[static_cast<int>(t::B)] = 2;
    m[static_cast<int>(t::C)] = 3;
    m[static_cast<int>(t::D)] = 4;
    for (int i : m)
       cout <<i;
    return 0;
}
```

(http://ideone.com/951Lcq)

Comment: у вас при выводе числа слипнуться, некрасиво это.

Comment: Если единственная цель использовать значения перечисления как числа, то `enum class` тут только добавляет проблем. Достаточно обычного `enum`.

Comment: @gbg Я просто переписал код из первого ответа :)